# Simple way`to rename resource to make it a friendly URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, url-rewriting

I have

resources :articles

and in article.rb

```
def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "_")}"
end
```

So the URL will be like

www.example.com/articles/1-Name-of-the-first-article

I am now trying to find a simple solution to always substitute "article" in the URL with "encyclopedia". So the path should be

www.example.com/encyclopedia/1-Name-of-the-first-article

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :articles, :path => :encyclopedia
```